# How to join two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 SQL Oracle datatables.

```
A:  Col1 | Col2 | Key
     c1      c2    1
     c3      c4    2
     c5      c6    3


B:  Co1  | Co2 | Key
      a1     a2    2
      a3     a4    3
```

I need select that gives me following table:

```
C:  
    a1  a2  c3 c4
    a3  a4  c5 c6
    -   -   c1 c2
```

How can I do it with SQL ? The normal Join:

```
select * from a, b where a.key = b.key;
```

does not give the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a left outer join:

```
select b.col1, b.col2, a.col1, a.col2
from a left outer join
     b 
     on a.key = b.key;
```

Comment: Works perfectly. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2aa79/4/0 Use `left outer join` when you want to have everything from the object on the left even if there's nothing related to the object on the right (of the left outer join)

Answer (score 2):

When doing a join like you are it will only return entries that exist in both tables.  To get the result that you are looking for try something like this...

```
SELECT B.Co1, B.Co2, A.Col1, A.Col2 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.Key = B.Key
```

Comment: The order of tables in from-clause is not right. Please check the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this query:

```
SELECT B.Co1, B.Co2, A.Col1, A.Col2 
FROM A,B
WHERE A.Key = B.Key(+);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you might try this:

```
SELECT b.Col1, b.Col2, a.Co1, a.Co2 FROM s
LEFT JOIN a ON a.Key = b.Key
```

[JOIN (INNER JOIN)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns. If there are rows in the "A" table that do not have matches in "B", these rows will NOT be listed.

[LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all the rows from the left table (A), even if there are no matches in the right table (B).

Comment: The order of tables in from-clause is not right. Please check the accepted answer.